# Installing a secondary drive in an HP Envy 17 laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, installation, ssd

I'm thinking about buying an [HP Envy 17](http://www.laptopshop.be/product/470175/hp-envy-17-j190nb-azerty.html). I like its specs but unfortunately it doesn't come pre-equipped with an SSD. If I'm reading [this HP manual](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04091762.pdf) correctly, it has a secondary SATA drive slot that's customer-replaceable. (Since the laptop config for my specific model only lists one drive, I'm assuming that it'll be an empty slot.) Here are some relevant parts from the documentation.

**Product description**
[image: Product description]

**About the secondary hard drive**
[image: Secondary hard drive install]

I rarely perform hardware upgrades myself before so I'll need some advice. I'm eyeing a Samsung 840 EVO SSD (120GB). Will I be able to install this drive in the primary slot and move the pre-installed drive to the secondary slot? Would I need any additional material to perform the installation? (An anti-static wristband? Certain cables/brackets that are sold separately?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is grab an SSD and put it into secondary slot. Then you can select boot hard drive from BIOS. Seriously, there is not first or second hard disk. About SSD, you should look for kits where it has additional equipment you might need. Like [this](https://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage/MZ-7TE250KW).

Comment: I vaguely recall reading something about a master/slave relationship between primary and secondary drives, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It was way too back when old IDE drives was existed. With SATA, there is not a problem like this as far as i know.

Answer (score -1):

I have an older 17" HP Pavilion DV7 running an Intel i7 2670, to which I successfully added another (SSD) dirve, transferred the operating system to the new drive and carried on.   I noted the boot time dropped substantially.

I believe the Envy is a similar machine in that it has TWO  internal HD drive bays and only one is normally occupied.

You will, however, need to get a mounting tray and HP cable to complete this addition.   Also you may need some mounting screws, if the tray vendor does not include them in the pack!

NzOldun